# Assign a friendly name to a data set item provided to an xUnit Theory, to be used for display in the results after the theory name

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit

I have started to use xUnit for unit tests. I have some test code working, and one test failing. The test data is provided via a MemberDataAttribute to the Theory.
When the tests are executed in Visual Studio Test Explorer I see the outcome of the tests, many passing, some failing.

The results look like TestCaseName(expected: 1234abcdef1234abdc....) where I see the hashcode of the object[] used as argumentum list for the invocation of the Theory method (or at least i presume it is that).

This is generally OK, but I'd like to know if there is an elegant way to provide a hint to xUnit to display some test dataset item identitifier for the individual cases?

I think it is clear how much easier it would make to navigate the test results with respect to the input data, and this is why I'm convinced that a solution is already provided by the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Override ToString() for your arguments.**

What you're actually seeing in the failed case is the ToString() result for all the objects in the object[] passed to the theory. If you override the ToString() methods for those classes (or make custom subclasses of those classes specifically to override ToString, something I occasionally do for classes that already have a ToString() designed to give information that's helpful elsewhere) then they will display exactly the information you want in failed test cases.

Comment: for the object[] I cannot override ToString() (of class Array). Neither can I override it for the constructor argument types, which are pretty much primitive types, but the array's ToString is called. 
 
One possible workaround I came up with is to use a Dictionary<string,object[]> where the keys are the testcase descriptions, and the [Theory] accepts these keys actually, and looks up the arguments manually. This way a type-safe N-tuple could also be used instead of the object[]

Comment: @kódfodrász (To clarify: it calls `ToString()` for each element in the `object[]` test case that fails, not on the `object[]` itself.) One of the arguments in your `object[]` is itself an array? Hmmm, I don't know that there's any way to create a custom ToString() for an array. Could you change your method to take an `IEnumerable<T>` instead? Then you could pass it a custom subclass of `List<T>` that overrides ToString() to give you useful information.

Comment: As far as I know the Theory (if has multiple arguments) accepts an object[] as these are the arguments passed to the method via reflection. On the other hand I could make the Theory accept a single object of a custom class, with my testcase data, and create a custom ToString(), and this way I'd not need the crazy Dictionary based idea I had. I'll do this as soon as I get back to that project.

Comment: @kódfodrász Yes, the contents of the object[] are passed, via reflection or just casting (I haven't investigated) to the Theory. If the Theory fails for that input, the ToString() for *each* of the elements in the object[] is included in the failure message.